# How to set the R_HOME environment variable to the R home directory?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to import rpy2 into python and I am getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: The R home directory could not be determined.
Try to install R <https://www.r-project.org/>,
set the R_HOME environment variable to the R home directory, or
add the directory of the R interpreter to the PATH environment variable.
```

I am completely lost here as I have no idea what this is telling me. I tried to search up how to set the environment variable and couldn't find anything detailed enough that was helpful for me. I would appreciate it if the answer could be very straightforward as I am just a newbie. I am running OSX 10.11.

Thank you (my first post, I apologize if I overlooked any rules in posting)

Comment: I tried to set up the R_HOME but get this error - ``WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME
/usr/local/lib/R``

Did you solve it?

Answer (score 14):

Setting R_HOME this way worked for me

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/path/to/R'
```

Answer (score 10):

It is the other way around -- the R in your `PATH` should know its home:

```
edd@don:~$ R RHOME
/usr/lib/R
edd@don:~$
```

This echos the last line recommendation -- have your R in the `PATH`.

On another machine with both R and R-devel, I choose to address the latter under a different name. Still, each knows its `HOME`:

```
edd@max:~$ /usr/local/lib/R-devel/bin/R RHOME
/usr/local/lib/R-devel/lib/R
edd@max:~$ R RHOME
/usr/lib/R
edd@max:~$
```

Comment: Ok, so how do I check the directory for my R interpreter and subsequently, how do I add it to PATH?

Comment: `export PATH=<directory>/${PATH}`. Also, it is generally advised to leave OSX's system Python alone. Consider using "homebrew" (and may be also install R with homebrew - things should work out of the box then).