# (Solved) Error "Unable to determine R home: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'R'" while trying "from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri" on mac

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to use some R packages while using python on mac. When I type in Jupyter lab

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
```

I get this error:

```
Unable to determine R home: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'R'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[44], line 11
      8 #import rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks
      9 import logging
---> 11 from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py:16
     14 import types
     15 import typing
---> 16 import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
     17 import rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded
     18 import rpy2.rinterface_lib.openrlib

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py:19
     17 import warnings
     18 from typing import Union
---> 19 from rpy2.rinterface_lib import openrlib
     20 import rpy2.rinterface_lib._rinterface_capi as _rinterface
     21 import rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded as embedded

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/openrlib.py:58
     56     rlib = _rinterface_cffi.lib
     57 else:
---> 58     rlib = _dlopen_rlib(R_HOME)
     61 # R macros and functions
     62 def _get_symbol_or_fallback(symbol: str, fallback: typing.Any):

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/openrlib.py:45, in _dlopen_rlib(r_home)
     41 """Open R's shared C library.
     42 
     43 This is only relevant in ABI mode."""
     44 if r_home is None:
---> 45     raise ValueError('r_home is None. '
     46                      'Try python -m rpy2.situation')
     47 lib_path = rpy2.situation.get_rlib_path(r_home, platform.system())
     48 if lib_path is None:

ValueError: r_home is None. Try python -m rpy2.situation
```

Any idea how might I solve this problem?

I suppose that I have to set a variable for r_home but I dont know how can I do that. I checked these:

```
> system("type R")
R is /usr/local/bin/R
> R.home()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
> file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R"
```

When I check where is R in my computer, I see:

" /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources "

Comment: I just solved it by using something suggested here: ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769545/errors-about-r-home-when-importing-rpy2-submodule?rq=2)). Namely: `import os

os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources'`