# When I call packages from rpy2 it gives me an error

Tags: python, rpy2

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
     from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
     from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
```

It raises an error:

```
ValueError: r_home is None. Try python -m rpy2.situation
```

I tried googleing but I don't find an answer. I use Linux and python3

Thank you for your help

Comment: Where in your code is the ValueError thrown?

Comment: From the first line and it transfers me to site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/openrlib.py

Comment: have you set R_HOME as an environment variable?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Rhome.html) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698877/how-to-setup-environment-variable-r-user-to-use-rpy2-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194876/how-to-set-the-r-home-environment-variable-to-the-r-home-directory)

Comment: cannot load library '/anaconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib/libR.so': /anaconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib/libR.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory it says this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Search for the path of your R installation (e.g. C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1)
2. Use the following code before importing rpy2:

   `import os`
   `os.environ['R_HOME'] = "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1" #or whereever your R is installed`

This works for me (but only temporarily)