# Error when importing rpy2.robjects : "R_HOME must be set in the environment or Registry"

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables, registry, rpy2

I would like to use the R function r_smooth_spline() in Python. In oder to do that, I need to import rpy2.robjects. But I obtain the error "R_HOME must be set in the environment or Registry"..

I spent hours looking for a solution but didn't find one..

Thank you

ps: I use anaconda on windows

Comment: There is simmilar question on stackoverflow. Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40790597/11061257)

Comment: thank you! I forgot to say that I tried this answer but I can't find the path to R ? please could you tell me how can I find it ?

Comment: The issue would seem to be with the anaconda package as it would seem to allow an installation of rpy2 without R on the system (and without a warning about with). Look for information / documentation about adding R to the registry or `PATH` on Windows (the answer you are pointed to in a previous comment seems to be for UNIX-like systems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R\_HOME Error with rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573988/r-home-error-with-rpy2)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to add the 'R_HOME' environment variable.

1. Go to: Control Panel-->System-->Advanced-->Environment Variables.
2. Under 'System Variables' click New.
   -
3. Variable name: R_HOME
   - Variable value: C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2
4. Highlight the 'Path' variable and click Edit. Make sure that 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\bin' is somewhere in that long list of
   pathways.

Good luck!